# Counting a number and push each number into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to count a number that I pull from query string and push each into an array. so if the number is 3, I want to push 1, 2 and 3 as separate numbers into the array. The below code does not work:

```
$number = $_GET['tics'];
$items = array();
for($numbers = 0; $numbers<$number; $numbers++) {
    $items[] = $numbers;
}
```

var_dump shows an empty array with this code. any idea how to make this work?

I want the key to be "numbers" and the values to be 1, 2, 3 etc..

I am sure this is explained many times already on stack, but when searching I found only examples that was way to advanced for someone like me

Comment: try `$number = (int)$_GET['tics']`

Comment: The array certainly shouldn't be empty with this code, although you'll get `[0, 1, 2]` instead of `[1, 2, 3]`. Are you sure you're looking at the right query string parameter? Is it definitely a number? What do you mean you "want the key to be numbers"? Which key?

Comment: Maybe it's $_POST and not $_GET? You send it via form or with parameters in URL?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're posting instead... could be.  https://ideone.com/ceZmxp

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I set `$number` to a number.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

> Returns an array of elements from start to end, inclusive.

```
$number = (int) $_GET['tics'];
$items = range(1, $number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php to generate a list of numbers from min to max.

```
<?php
$number = 5;

// Do validation on $number before passing it to range. 

$result = range(1, $number);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, **your loop is incorrect**.

If you pass `$number = 3`

```
for ($numbers = 0; $numbers < $number; $numbers++) {
```

Will give you 0, 1, 2. You need to change it to the following:

```
for ($numbers = 1; $numbers <= $number; $numbers++) {
```

This will give you 1, 2, 3.

---

Anyway, entertaining another idea here, if [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) as mentioned by the other answers is not what you require.

> I want the key to be "numbers" and the values to be 1, 2, 3 etc..

It's not exactly clear what you mean by this, but I'm guessing you might want the array keys to be the value of `$numbers`? In which case, you can modify your code as follows:

```
$number = (int)$_GET['tics'];
$items = array();
for ($numbers = 1; $numbers <= $number; $numbers++) {
    $items[$numbers] = $numbers;
}
```

---

Your code should somewhat work as intended anyway (the numbers will be incorrect). The reason it doesn't is probably that `$_GET['tics']` has no value. Ensure that you do indeed have `tics` in the `$_GET` array, and that you aren't actually POSTing (in which case you need `$_POST['tics']` instead).

If you change `$_GET` in your code to `$_POST` and it still doesn't work, then `tics` is either not set or does not have a value greater than 0.